# What do I use the curse and coin randomizer cards for?

Tags: dominion

I have the big box Dominion which includes Prosperity and Alchemy. It came with randomizer (purple-backed distinct) cards for curses and coins. What are these used for?

I understand the Kingdom randomizer cards can be used for playing with unknown Kingdom cards sets.